# jQuery toggle / slide resetting links

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

I made a toggle script for some text on a website. I have about 10 "head" links and two h3 links. Basically if you click one head link it opens and closes by clicking it again. If you click on the h3 all of them open. If ones already open it keeps it open. One problem is if you open them all then close and open just one and then try to close them all you have to click h3 twice. This is because when opened by themselves it gives a class of active1 and when opened all together it gives class of active. So when I hit h3 the first time it turns active1 into active (this is so they can all close or open in a situation where only one is open and you want to open them all) and then the 2nd time it finally closes all the active. Hope that makes sense.

Here is the [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry6Nr/).

```
$(".topics").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of functionality you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/Ry6Nr/8/ ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".topics").hide();        
    $(".head").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

The `toggleClass` and `slideToggle` functions do what I think you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use 2 classes when you can do with just one?  It's just to tell you which ones are open or not.

```
$("h3").click(function() {
    var $div = $(this).siblings('.head'); // cache the relative divs
    var len = $div.filter('.active').length; // get how many are active
    var $topic = $(".topics", $(this).parent()); // topics relative to element
    if (len == $div.length) { // if all are active
        $div.removeClass('active'); // remove class active
        $topic.slideUp(350); // slideup
    } else {
        $div.addClass('active'); // else add active to all
        $topic.slideDown(350) //  slide down
    }
});

$(".head").click(function() {
    var $el = $(this); // cache this
    if ($el.hasClass("active")) {
        $el.removeClass("active").next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $el.addClass("active").next().slideDown(350);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmsJa/

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! I am very new to jQuery. Sometimes I make things knowing there is any easier way but I just don't know to do it just yet. Thank you very much

Comment: @user1842315 You're welcome :) hope this was what you were looking for.. Also check the green checkmark if this answered your question

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry6Nr/9/) updated jsFiddle.

Original code:

```
 if( $(".head").hasClass("active1") ){
    $(".head").removeClass("active1").addClass("active").next().slideDown(350);
        } else
```

Upadted code:

```
$("h3").click(function(){
    if( $(".head").hasClass("active1") ){
    $(".head").removeClass("active1").next().slideUp(350);
        }
```